# Rounding corners of delete button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to round the corners of my UITableViewCell delete button. I would also like to make it the same height as the container view for my cell.

I have searched around, but all I could find was how to change the image inside of the delete button.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Tried to post an image, unfortunately I do not have enough reputation as this is my first post.

Comment: better if you show with your work, it will help others to understand your problem

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read this before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I will be sure to work on my posting skills in the future :)

Comment: hello @DanielReiling , any change you found a solution for this problem? I am trying to do exactly the same thing you wanted to do and find no straightforward answer. Did you end up using SwipeCellKit?

Comment: @regina_fallangi No unfortunately I did not find answer to this problem in the time that I had available. I admittedly did not do an exhaustive search for more options. I also did not get the chance to try SwipeCellKit. Sorry I could not have been of more help.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This might be of some help to anyone looking to have a different solution to the standard rectangular swipe action button.

Swift 5

Adding a delete action with a white trash can image and then using the extension to add a backing circle about twice the size of the original image.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    var actions = [UIContextualAction]()

    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (contextualAction, view, completion) in

        // Delete something

        completion(true)
    }

    let largeConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 17.0, weight: .bold, scale: .large)
    delete.image = UIImage(systemName: "trash", withConfiguration: largeConfig)?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate).addBackgroundCircle(.systemRed)
    delete.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    delete.title = "Delete"

    actions.append(delete)

    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: actions)
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false

    return config
}
```

An extension to add a background circle of any color to a UIImage.

```
extension UIImage {

    func addBackgroundCircle(_ color: UIColor?) -> UIImage? {

        let circleDiameter = max(size.width * 2, size.height * 2)
        let circleRadius = circleDiameter * 0.5
        let circleSize = CGSize(width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter)
        let circleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleSize.width, height: circleSize.height)
        let imageFrame = CGRect(x: circleRadius - (size.width * 0.5), y: circleRadius - (size.height * 0.5), width: size.width, height: size.height)

        let view = UIView(frame: circleFrame)
        view.backgroundColor = color ?? .systemRed
        view.layer.cornerRadius = circleDiameter * 0.5

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(circleSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: circleSize)
        let circleImage = renderer.image { ctx in
            view.drawHierarchy(in: circleFrame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }

        circleImage.draw(in: circleFrame, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
        draw(in: imageFrame, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)

        let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about the swipe-to-delete UITableViewRowAction, there is no way to do that. Those row actions are surprisingly inflexible appearance-wise. You will need to implement your own via a gesture-recognizer based solution. Now, there's enough complexity in doing this that, if you *really* want this feature, I'd suggest using a 3rd party dependency like [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit). If it were me, I'd classify this appearance tweak as not worth the time investment (or worth adding a dependency) and go a different route.

Comment: Thank you @Conner, I have been looking for a while and could not find anything that did not implement a custom solution. I was hoping I was missing some built in functionality. I think I will take your advise and take another route.