# Round delete button in tableview editStyle method

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

**My code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        self.tmakeAlertDialog(title: "Hello".localized(),
                              message: "Are you sure you want to delete the sound?".localized(),
                              actions: [.init(title: "Yes".localized(), style: .default, handler: { _ in self.deleteSoundAction(indexPath)}),
                                        .init(title: "No".localized(), style: .default)]) { _ in }
    }
}
```

**My TableView**

[image]

I want to round the delete button.

[Rounding corners of delete button in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183628/rounding-corners-of-delete-button-in-uitableviewcell)

I tried this answer but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As per the link in your question, you can try to create image with "Delete" text using NSAttributedString.draw API. Use that to update the image of UIContextAction object's image and don't set the title.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        var actions = [UIContextualAction]()
        print(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.bounds)

        let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (contextualAction, view, completion) in

            print(view.frame)
            // Delete something

            completion(true)
        }

      
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 90, height: 52))
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
            
            let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40),
                .strokeColor: UIColor.black,
                .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ]
            
            let string = "Delete"
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attrs)
            
            attributedString.draw(with: .zero, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        }

        delete.image = img.addBackgroundCircle(.systemRed)
        actions.append(delete)

        let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: actions)
        config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false

        return config
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly do I need to add this code and do I need to get the code from the link I shared?

Comment: updated the code above.. Yes, just modified the answer provided in the link..

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: it works for me.. Delete button inside a red circle.. Are you still getting rectangular output?

Comment: I deleted the editingStyle method and wrote the one you gave directly and deleted the override part because it gave an error "There is no such method". I also wrote the Extension codes in the link. And it doesn't even slip, so the wiping part is not visible at all.

Comment: You need to override this function tableView(_:canEditRowAt:) for the row to be editable.

Comment: If I override ( _: canEditRowAt: ) I cannot perform an action on the row.